# Value of parametric constant t in Plane and Ray intersection?

Tags: c++, math, graphics, opencl, plane

I am implementing ray and rectangle intersection test . For that first I test if ray is intersecting plane if it does then I see if it lies in bounds of rectangle.

Following is the code:

```
float intersectQuad(Ray r, float3 p1, float3 p2, float3 p3, float3 p4, float3* normal)
{
   float3 x1 = p2 - p1;
   float3 x2 = p4 - p1;
   float t;

   float3 n = normalize(cross(x2, x1));
   float denom = dot(n, r.dir); 

    if (denom > 0.00000000001) 
    { 
       float3 p0l0 = normalize(p1 - r.origin); 
       t = dot(p0l0, n) / denom; 

       printf(" %f ", t);

       if( t > 0.000000000001f )
       {
         float3 hitPoint = r.origin + r.dir * t;

         float3 V1 = normalize(p2 - p1);
         float3 V2 = normalize(p3 - p2);
         float3 V3 = normalize(p4 - p3);
         float3 V4 = normalize(p1 - p4);
         float3 V5 = normalize(hitPoint - p1);
         float3 V6 = normalize(hitPoint - p2);
         float3 V7 = normalize(hitPoint - p3);
         float3 V8 = normalize(hitPoint - p4);

         if (dot(V1,V5) < 0.0f) return 0.0f;
         if (dot(V2,V6) < 0.0f) return 0.0f;
         if (dot(V3,V7) < 0.0f) return 0.0f;
         if (dot(V4,V8) < 0.0f) return 0.0f;

         *normal = n;
         return t;
       }
    } 

 return 0.0f; 
}
```

My understanding is the value of `t` should be `0.0f < t < 1.0f` 
but when I print values of `t` I some time see values `> 1.0f`.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Given that the ray direction vector is normalized for ray.origin + ray.direction*t then t is the distance from the origin to the "hitpoint". That distance can have any value.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the ray direction vector is normalized for `r.origin + r.direction*t` then `t` is the distance from the origin to the `hitPoint`. That distance can have any value.

Second, I would change the return value type to `bool` serving the purpose of avoiding floating point arithmetic to compare the result to 0.0f again in the function's calling scope..

Third, more as a matter of personal taste, reformat the code the following way using the early exit technique and marking `const` values where ever possible.

```
bool intersectQuad(Ray r, float3 p1, float3 p2, float3 p3, float3 p4, float3* outNormal, float* outT)
{
   const float3 x1 = p2 - p1;
   const float3 x2 = p4 - p1;
   const float3 n = normalize(cross(x2, x1));
   const float denom = dot(n, r.dir); 

   if (denom < 0.00000000001) return false;

   const float3 p0l0 = normalize(p1 - r.origin); 
   const float t = dot(p0l0, n) / denom; 

   printf(" %f ", t);

   if( t < 0.000000000001f ) return false;

   const float3 hitPoint = r.origin + r.dir * t;

   const float3 V1 = normalize(p2 - p1);
   const float3 V2 = normalize(p3 - p2);
   const float3 V3 = normalize(p4 - p3);
   const float3 V4 = normalize(p1 - p4);
   const float3 V5 = normalize(hitPoint - p1);
   const float3 V6 = normalize(hitPoint - p2);
   const float3 V7 = normalize(hitPoint - p3);
   const float3 V8 = normalize(hitPoint - p4);

   if (dot(V1,V5) < 0.0f) return false;
   if (dot(V2,V6) < 0.0f) return false;
   if (dot(V3,V7) < 0.0f) return false;
   if (dot(V4,V8) < 0.0f) return false;

   *outNormal = n;
   *outT = t;
   return true;
}
```